# activity indicator in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

i was trying to animate the `UIActivityindicator` at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i.e when row is selected it should start animating until other view is not loaded. i was trying code but it does nothing, help!!!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self. indicator stopAnimating];
        if(bdvController == nil)
        bdvController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {       
        Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        bdvController.aBook = aBook;
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5*indexPath.section];
    bdvController.aBook = aBook;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvController animated:YES];
 }


- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    return indexPath;

}
```

Comment: I think this `[self.indicator.startAnimating];` should be `[self.indicator startAnimating];`.

Comment: @Nick: ya ,i have seen... It is my mistake. It should be like you recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly 
[self.indicator.startAnimating]; what are you trying to do on this line ? Are you accessing a property or calling a method .
And I think it will wait for the didSelectRow  method completion to display the indiacator . May be you can try displaying the indicator in

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and do the processing in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As you have not pasted code related to indicator creation. Hope you have set the selection style of the table view cell to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone and have also set the appropriate frame for indicator view .

Comment: j: its mistake over there. i observed that and corrected it. I think you are right . ok! i am trying to do this in NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

Comment: -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [indicator startAnimating];
 return indexPath; 
}
nothing is happening

Comment: which lines of code i have to write in willSelectRowAtIndex mthod

Comment: this didnt work for me..i think you better check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342553/activity-indicators-when-pushing-next-view-didselectrowatindexpath

Answer (score 1):

Create a **NSThread** as call a selector as follows :

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) 
                         toTarget:self 
                       withObject:nil];    
// Your code    
[spinner stopAnimating];    
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

threadStartAnimating:

```
-(void)threadStartAnimating:(id)data    
{    
    [spinner startAnimating];    
}
```

Comment: its not doing what i need..I think Bharat is saying correct !! let me check if according to Bharat.

Comment: @user720235 : Is it working now ? If not then if you could paste some more code , we will be able to trace the issue ...