# Activity Indicators when pushing next view - didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

I can successfully push only next view in my iPhone app. However, cause the next view retrieves data to populate the `UITableViews`, sometimes waiting time could be a few seconds or slightly longer depending on connection.

During this time, the user may think the app has frozen etc. So, to counter this problem, I think implementing `UIActivityIndicators` would be a good way to let the user know that the app is working.

Can someone tell me where I could implement this?

Thanks.

**pushDetailView Method**

```
- (void)pushDetailView {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
//load the clicked cell.
DetailsImageCell *cell = (DetailsImageCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//init the controller.
AlertsDetailsView *controller = nil;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    controller = [[AlertsDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsView_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    controller = [[AlertsDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsView" bundle:nil];
}

//set the ID and call JSON in the controller.
[controller setID:[cell getID]];

//show the view.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method itself.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
cell.accessoryView = spinner;
[spinner startAnimating];
[spinner release];
```

This will show the activity indicator at the right side of the cell which will make the user feel that something is loading.

**Edit:** If you set the *accessoryView* and write the loading code in the same method, the UI will get updated only when all the operations over. A workaround for this is to just set the *activityIndicator* in the *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method and call the view controller pushing code with some delay.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    cell.accessoryView = spinner;
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [spinner release];

    [self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Push the detail view here
}
```

Comment: @Simon: Cool, I will try that. One question, I have had a few goes in doing this before but a few times, the activity indicator shows just when the view is pushed. Will this method above, make the activity indicator appear once the user has tapped on the cell? Thanks.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for your help. However, when I put my push detail view code in `pushDetailView`, I get 2 errors. **Use of undeclared indentifier 'tableView'**. My `pushDetailView` code is above. Thanks.

Comment: @K.Honda, I think you have created the tableview locally. You can declare the table view in header file or you can pass the table view to the *pushDetailViewController* method. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Simon: I have got rid of the **Use of undeclared indentifier 'tableView'** error. Unfortunately, I have got another error: **'indexPath' undeclared (first use in this function)**. How can we fix this? Thank you so much Simon.

Comment: @Simon: I have tried implementing this: `- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but it crashes with a **sigabrt**  at `[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0.1];`. I think I should add something there but don't know what. Do you know? Thanks.